# How to adjust the font style of tags with plot_annotation in figures assembled with patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have a figure assembled with `patchwork` as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

p1 + p2 + plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a')
```

[image]

How can I change the font face of tags so that the letters `a` and `b` appear in bold face?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After browsing [this page](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html), I found that tags of all subfigures can be modified with `&` operator:

```
p1 + p2 + plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a') &
    theme(plot.tag = element_text(face = 'bold'))
```

[image]